# What's the best way to manage a classic asp front-end using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, asp-classic

I support a third party system that uses COM, classic ASP, and SQL Server.  Our company has gone to using TFS as our source control provider - which pushes things through Visual Studio.  So, what's the best way to get a classic asp front-end into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 7):

When I had to do this, I created a blank solution in VS and then added the folders from the ASP site one at a time, adding "existing items" to each folder as I created it.

In this way I'm able to open the solution which keeps track of what files I had open at last open, plus I get the benefits of intellisense

Comment: By adding the folders one at a time, do you mean you recreated the folders by name using the 'add new solution folder' and then did an 'add existing item' for the files that belonged in that folder?  Is there a vs project type that this can be done within?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this frequently over the last 5 years...

You could create an Empty Website, or even create a standard (.NET) website and simply delete the default stuff it generates (web.config etc). Note: create a website, creates a solution and adds a website project within it, which is arguably slightly more preferable than simply adding files and folders to solution.

As Geoff says, you get most of the benefits of VS including intellisense.

Suck it and see... Have a fiddle - you are not going to break anything!

Answer (score 0):

Did any of you heard of Visual Web developer 2008 Express edition?
Work wonders for me.
Most important as soon as you ask to open website in it- it opens each folder of intended website and when you save project it does what you need to do to later open this website in regular visual studio.

It have some limited capability even to convert simple Classic ASP pages into NET  code!

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank solution in VS and add all the files by choosing "Add Existing Item.."